# Cauchy Problem, extended solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that for $x_0\neq 0$ the Cauchy problem: 
$$x'=\frac{t+x^2}{t-x},\quad  x(0)=x_0,$$ 
has a unique solution in a neighbourhood of $t=0$ and that it can not be extended to all $t>0$.

Comment: Hi, can you tell us what you are currently studying to provide context? Regards

Comment: I'm studing differential equations

Comment: It's not a book.I 've find this exercise from a competition. I've studied uniqueness,existence,stability

Comment: Using the cauchy theorem we can prove that exists a unic solution in a neighbourhood of 0 because the function has derivate rispect the second variable continous ($x_0\neq 0$).But I can't find the way to prove that it can not be extended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [already know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461889/cauchy-problem-extended-solution#comment995569_461889) how to prove local existence and uniqueness. For inextensible what you need is to split into two cases:

Let me sketch out the argument for you (you can try to make precise on your own):

If $x < 0$ at any positive time, the equation implies that $x' > 1$ since $t-x > 0$ and $t+x^2 - (t-x) = x^2 - x > 0$. So if $x_0 < 0$, within time $T < |x_0|$ the solution $x$ will increase until $x = 0$, at which time $x'$ blows up.

If $x > t > 0$ at any positive time, the equation implies that $t-x < 0$ and so $x' < 0$. This implies that for $x_0 > 0$ the solution $x < x_0$ until $t$ increases to the point $t = x$. But then again $t-x = 0$ and $x'$ blows up. Since $x_0$ is finite it takes at most $T = |x_0|$ time before $t$ catches up to $x$.

So the conclusion is that the solution blows up for all non-zero initial data in time $T \leq |x_0|$.